# Qual a diferença entre Constructors e Factories em JS?

Tags: javascript

Estudando fiquei com essa dúvida, pois os 2 me parecem QUASE a mesma coisa, porém enquanto a Factory retorna um objeto quando a função é executada (as propriedades e funções não utilizam o `this`, nesse caso são utilizadas closures), o constructor precisa ser chamado com a keyword `new` (cria um novo objeto e binda o this para esse novo objeto criado).

Além disso as factories podem fazer encapsulamento, retornando somente aquilo que queremos que o usuário veja.

É isso? Estou enganado? Mesmo achando que sei fiquei bem confuso nessa parte.

Answer (score 3):

## FACTORY X CONSTRUCTOR

A maior diferença entre os Construtores e os Factorys além do operador `new`, é que os Factorys retornam um objeto, enquanto os Constructors não. Vamos a um exemplo:

```
//Fábrica
function PessoaFactory(nome){
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.nome = nome;
    return obj;
};

//Construtor
function PessoaConstructor(nome){
    this.nome = nome;
};
```

O fábrica cria um novo objeto, seta seus atributos e o retorna. Poderia usa-la dessa forma:

```
let pessoa1 = PessoaFactory('Pedro');
console.log(pessoa.nome) //Pedro
```

Já a função Construtora trabalha de uma forma diferente:

```
let pessoa2 = new PessoaConstructor('Maria');
console.log(pessoa2.nome); //Maria
```

Até ai, quase a mesma sintaxe da função Factory, mas quando usamos o operador `new`, por debaixo dos panos, é criado um novo objeto vazio e depois feita uma chamada para a função `call` passando o objeto que acabou de ser criado como contexto:

Quando você usa essa sintaxe:

```
let pessoa2 = new PessoaConstructor('Maria');
console.log(pessoa2.nome); //Maria
```

Por debaixo dos panos acontece isso:

```
let pessoa2 = {}
PessoaConstructor.call(pessoa2, 'Maria');
console.log(pessoa2.nome); //Maria
```

A funcão `PessoaConstructor` é executada no contexto do objeto `pessoa2`, isso faz com que o `this.nome` dentro da função construtora passe a ser um atributo do objeto `pessoa2`, que recebe o parâmetro passado para a função construtora;